# Amazon Echo Dot only visible as input device, not output

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, output

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS installed on a desktop computer, and I also have an [Amazon Echo Dot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PGL2N7J). My desktop communicates to the Echo Dot via bluetooth, and connects successfully. [This is the bluetooth dongle being used](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CTFVXLL). The trouble is that the Echo Dot shows up as an input device (recording my voice), and I have been unable to get it to work as an output device (playing audio from my computer). The Echo Dot is capable of playing audio from my cell phone over bluetooth without issue. I also tried connecting my wireless earbuds to the desktop, and was able to play audio from the desktop through the earbuds.

Some informative text from the terminal is pasted below (or at least I hope so; I'm new to Linux). I tried installing Blueman and making it pair to the audio sink. Even after forgetting the device and reconnecting, this was ineffective. Nothing I can do seems to allow this device to play sound from my computer. Please help!

```
pactl list short sinks
5   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING

pacmd list-cards
....
    index: 3
name: <bluez_card.CC_9E_A2_15_EC_BA>
driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
owner module: 27
properties:
    device.description = "Echo-X8G"
    device.string = "CC:9E:A2:15:EC:BA"
    device.api = "bluez"
    device.class = "sound"
    device.bus = "bluetooth"
    device.form_factor = "speaker"
    bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_9E_A2_15_EC_BA"
    bluez.class = "0x2c0414"
    bluez.alias = "Echo-X8G"
    device.icon_name = "audio-speakers-bluetooth"
profiles:
    a2dp_source: High Fidelity Capture (A2DP Source) (priority 20, available: yes)
    a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: no)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
active profile: <a2dp_source>
sources:
    bluez_source.CC_9E_A2_15_EC_BA.a2dp_source/#4: Echo-X8G
ports:
    speaker-output: Speaker (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:

    speaker-input: Bluetooth Input (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:

set-card-profile 3 a2dp_sink
Failed to set card profile to 'a2dp_sink'.
```

[I already checked this similar question. The solution did not work for me, unfortunately.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950477/amazon-echo-alexa-now-only-shows-up-as-an-input-device)